# Angular 2 error messages

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to make some error messages for my application, i have made it like this

```
<span *ngIf="email.hasError('required')">Please enter your e-mail address</span>
<span *ngIf="email.hasError('email') && !email.hasError('required')">Please enter a valid e-mail address</span>
```

But i dont like how it look, maybe someone can help me make it shorthand?

Comment: I'm not really sure there's a better way to do this, tracking those values in the component would likely be even more complex.  What exactly are you hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

You could perform your validation in your code and then bind to the result.

Here is what one of mine looks like:

```
<span class="help-block" *ngIf="displayMessage.productName">
  {{displayMessage.productName}}
</span>
```

I then have a property in my component that tracks the validation state:

```
displayMessage: { [key: string]: string } = {};
```

Hope that leads you down the right path.

If you want to look at my solution in more detail, you can find it here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms in the APM-Updated folder.

(This code is from my "Angular Reactive Forms" course on Pluralsight.)